# How to re-attach Persistent Volume?

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

I've got this `PersistentVolume`:

```
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS     CLAIM                    STORAGECLASS               REASON   AGE
pvc-01e19eb3-3d62-4772-bd49-1de4f08d5e81   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Released   kymark/mariadb-pvc       persistent-block-storage            10d
```

But I deleted the PVC.

If I create a new PVC, how can I specify that I want to re-use that same existing PV? i.e. I want the same data back.

For reference, my PVC YAML looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mariadb-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce 
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: persistent-block-storage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose Retain as the reclaim policy, you cannot attach PV to another PVC unless you manually delete the associated storage asset(delete the claimRef field with `kubectl edit pv pvc-01e19eb3-3d62-4772-bd49-1de4f08d5e81`).

```
The Retain reclaim policy allows for manual reclamation of the resource. When the PersistentVolumeClaim is deleted, the PersistentVolume still exists and the volume is considered "released". But it is not yet available for another claim because the previous claimant's data remains on the volume. An administrator can manually reclaim the volume with the following steps.

Delete the PersistentVolume. The associated storage asset in external infrastructure (such as an AWS EBS, GCE PD, Azure Disk, or Cinder volume) still exists after the PV is deleted.

Manually clean up the data on the associated storage asset accordingly.

Manually delete the associated storage asset, or if you want to reuse the same storage asset, create a new PersistentVolume with the storage asset definition.
```

Comment: Wait, so if I leave the PV as "delete" it won't actually delete my data when I delete the PVC? And then what..? How do I re-attach it? How will the new PVC knows it belongs with that old PV?

Comment: For volume plugins that support the Delete reclaim policy, deletion removes both the PersistentVolume object from Kubernetes, as well as the associated storage asset in the external infrastructure

You can get more details from the following link.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaiming